# Model Attributes not being set by Collection.fetch() in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I have this code:

```
app.Collections.quotes = new app.Collections.Quotes();
    app.Collections.quotes.fetch({
        success: function(){
            console.log(app.Collections.quotes.at(0).get("NetAmount"));
        }
    });
```

Console.log returns 'undefined'.

Yet, I can see the returned response from the server is an array of Objects and Backbone does actually create 27 models, but none of them have any attributes!

Any ideas?

Comment: `app.Collections.quotes.toJSON()` shows empty models?

Comment: Do you have specified the `model` attribute in the collection?

Comment: And have you by any chance overridden `Collection.parse` or `Model.parse`?

Comment: YES @fencliff thank you! I had an empty "parse: function(){};" in my Model for some reason. Took it out. BAM. Insta-models!

Comment: @fencliff Can you add that as an answer, so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Sure thing. I tried to put a generic spin on it, in case someone ends up here later via search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per question comments, it looks like you may have overridden `Model.parse`. If you do, you need to return the attributes hash you want to set as the model's attributes:

```
parse: function(response) {
  //do something with response
  return response;
}
```